# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on reboot and boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell inspiron 5577 NVIDIA GTX 1050. On rebooting from live install, system freezes.

I have referred various articles to install NVIDIA drivers. So I chrooted into the installed Ubuntu from the live Ubuntu system.

After which I observed that:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

returns nothing.

```
lspci -k
```

Does not show any drivers related to graphics. Also it shows the following error:

```
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
```

So, I installed NVIDIA driver 390.

```
add-apt-get ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install nvidia-390
```

Followed by

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Which shows the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Warning: couldn't identify filesystem type for fsck hook, ignoring.
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-390.77 DKMS files...
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 210: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 390.77
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-390.77 DKMS files...
grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
Building for 4.15.0-29-generic 4.15.0-32-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 2017: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 1949: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-390:
 nvidia-390 depends on nvidia-driver-390; however:
  Package nvidia-driver-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Warning: couldn't identify filesystem type for fsck hook, ignoring.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-390
 nvidia-driver-390
 nvidia-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On boot up, after waiting for sometime, An `fsck` error is shown followed by `journalctl` output and `watchdog cpu#4 softlock`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem:

With HP Zbook:

On Bios,I set Graphic: Discrete ( instead of hybrid or Auto), it fixed the problem!!!

It is definitely a hardware conflict with os!

Comment: Hi, Rastin.  Please don't post the same answer to many different questions; this is usually considered "noise".  Instead, if the questions are similar enough, flag them as potential duplicates of each other rather than reposting the same answer everywhere.  Thanks!